# Uninstalling software on linux

Tags: linux

I want to uninstalll software installed after compiling packages with

```
make
```

and installed with

```
make install
```

I am using Linux Mint Debian i know that the software installed using apt can be removed using

```
sudo apt-get remove {package-name}
```

But i am looking for a method to uninstall software installed otherwise

Answer (score 2):

If you still have the original source tree, it *might* support a "`make uninstall`".

If not, you'll have to figure out which files were copied where by the "`make install`", and delete them manually.  "`make install`" scripts generally don't keep any records of what they've installed for automatic uninstallation purposes.  (This is why package systems like apt were invented!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an additional tool, like [checkinstall](http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/checkinstall), to keep track of what files have been installed.

Make sure to use a [different prefix](https://wiki.debian.org/CheckInstall) than usual software, so as not to clash, like this:

```
./configure --with-prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo checkinstall make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll through the list of installed packages in the Terminal window to find the one you want to uninstall. Note the full name of the package. To uninstall a program, use the “apt-get” command, which is the general command for installing programs and manipulating installed programs

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this does not resolve the problem as the software was not installed via apt rather using make